# Collapse items of Angular-NestedSortable / angular-ui-tree

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, nested-sortable

we're trying Angular-NestedSortable https://github.com/subvertnormality/Angular-NestedSortable (the version 2 of angular-ui-tree doesn't look stable yet, looking at the tests).
We'd like to load the tree structure via REST and then collapse the root nodes.
Also, we'd like to make additional REST requests when an item is expanded.
We have problems because the NestedSortable uses lots of nested Angular scopes and we don't understand how to access API methods like collapseAll() or how to overload toggle().
Can someone provide an example fiddle or plunkr or so?
That doesn't work:
`$scope.list = [...]; $scope.collapseAll();`
because `collapseAll` is not defined in the outer scope...

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way, 
create the tamplate with your treeView nodes.

IMPORTANT:

1. **callRestService()** // the function
2. **data-collapsed="node.collapsed"** // set true or false, node.**collapsed** is a propery of your model

example:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_nodes.html">
    <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content" ng-mouseover="showButtons=true" ng-mouseleave="showButtons=false">
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this); callRestService(this)">
            <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed}"></span>
        </a>
        {{node.Name}}
        <a ng-show="showButtons" class="pull-right" style="cursor:pointer;" data-nodrag ng-click="remove(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        <a ng-show="showButtons" class="pull-right" style="cursor:pointer;margin-right: 8px;" data-nodrag ng-click="newSubItem(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
    </div>
    <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="node.nodes" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
        <li ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" data-collapsed="node.collapsed" ui-tree-node ng-include="'tree_nodes.html'">
        </li>
    </ol>
</script>

<div ui-tree id="tree-root">
    <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="data">
        <li ng-repeat="node in data" ui-tree-node data-collapsed="node.collapsed" ng-include="'tree_nodes.html'"></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```